# Transform vector of reference wrapper to Base class to vector of reference_wrapper to Derived class cannot dynamic cast

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, reference-wrapper

As in title. I got this error when trying to dynamic_cast

> cannot dynamic_cast '(&
>   obj)->std::reference_wrapper<_Tp>::get()' (of type 'class
>   MEPObject') to type 'class MEPGene&' (target is not pointer or
>   reference to complete type)
>            genes.push_back(dynamic_cast (obj.get()));

```
class MEPObject;
class MEPGene;
typedef std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<MEPObject>> MEPObjects;
typedef std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<MEPGene>> MEPGenes;

void dynamicCast(MEPObjects &objects, MEPGenes &genes)
{
    for(const auto &obj: objects)
    {
        genes.push_back(dynamic_cast<MEPGene&> (obj.get()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forward declaration is not enough.

Definition of `MEPGene` is required (to see inheritance).